# Можно ли этот код реализовать одним linq запросом?

Tags: c#, linq

Подскажите, можно ли приведенный ниже код в методе GetContinuationNgram, реализовать одним запросом LINQ, без foreach?

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> frecuent = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    frecuent["hello"] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    frecuent["hello"].Add("bye", 2);
    frecuent["hello"].Add("dolly", 3);
    frecuent["hello"].Add("baby", 2);
    frecuent["bye"] = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    frecuent["bye"].Add("bro", 6);
    frecuent["bye"].Add("man", 2);
    frecuent["bye"].Add("'miss", 6);

    frecuent.Dump();
    var res = GetContinuationNgram(frecuent).Dump();
}

public static Dictionary<string, string> GetContinuationNgram(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> frecuent)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var dict in frecuent)
    {
        var max = dict.Value.Max(s => s.Value);
        result[dict.Key] = dict.Value
            .Where(s => s.Value.Equals(max))
            .Select(s => s.Key)
            .OrderBy(s => s, StringComparer.Ordinal)
            .First();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Это пример работы:
[image: выбор самого частотного продолжения слова]

Comment: `frecuent.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.OrderByDescending(ikvp => ikvp.Value).ThenBy(ikvp => ikvp.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal).First().Key)`

Comment: @PetSerAl Спасибо, очень помогли. А то я сляпал свое решение, а как у вас сделать, никак не доходило - не мог отойти от логики прохода по циклам в циклах. Но теперь уж разберусь.

Comment: @PetSerAl, оформите как ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetContinuationNgram_Updated(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> frecuent)
{
    return frecuent
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value
            .Where(y => y.Value.Equals(x.Value.Max(z => z.Value)))
            .Select(y => y.Key)
            .OrderBy(y => y, StringComparer.Ordinal)
            .First()
        );
}
```

[image: сравнение методов]